# Detect edges in an image

Tags: ios, graphics

I have an image of a room.  I want to detect the edges in the image - i.e. draw a line around the ceiling or say around a window.  How hard a problem is this - are there any libraries that do this?

This is for a iOS app but my question is platform / language independent.

Comment: There are couple good Edge Detection algorithms you could try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection Sobel, Prewitt

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example from openCV source code called edge.cpp
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/
Its quite a lot of fun building and running the sample apps (/sample dir)

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int edgeThresh = 1;
Mat image, gray, edge, cedge;

// define a trackbar callback
static void onTrackbar(int, void*)
{
 blur(gray, edge, Size(3,3));

// Run the edge detector on grayscale
Canny(edge, edge, edgeThresh, edgeThresh*3, 3);
cedge = Scalar::all(0);

image.copyTo(cedge, edge);
imshow("Edge map", cedge);
}

static void help()
{
printf("\nThis sample demonstrates Canny edge detection\n"
       "Call:\n"
       "    /.edge [image_name -- Default is fruits.jpg]\n\n"); 
}

const char* keys =
{
"{@image |fruits.jpg|input image name}"
};

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
help();

CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keys);
string filename = parser.get<string>(1);

image = imread(filename, 1);
if(image.empty())
{
    printf("Cannot read image file: %s\n", filename.c_str());
    help();
    return -1;
}
cedge.create(image.size(), image.type());
cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// Create a window
namedWindow("Edge map", 1);

// create a toolbar
createTrackbar("Canny threshold", "Edge map", &edgeThresh, 100, onTrackbar);

// Show the image
onTrackbar(0, 0);

// Wait for a key stroke; the same function arranges events processing
waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

if you want to build it separate to your openCV build you can use this script
(a version is provided under the c sample dir - I modified it to compile extra libraries)

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
base=`basename $1 .c`
echo "compiling $base"
gcc -ggdb `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` $base.c -o $base 
else
for i in *.c; do
    echo "compiling $i"
    gcc -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $i .c` $i `pkg-config --libs    opencv`;
done
for i in *.cpp; do
    echo "compiling $i"
    g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename $i .cpp` $i `pkg-config -- libs opencv` -lpthread -D_REENTRANT;
done
fi
```